# ionic emulate android on bootup still showing dots after 30 mins

Tags: android, ionic-framework

So I ran ionic emulate android and this is what I'm seeing on my console

```
Booting up emulator (this may take a while)..............................................................................................................................................................
```

It's still is continuing to show dots

I ran this to check if HAXM is loaded and looks good

```
$ kextstat | grep intel
161    0 0xffffff7f839aa000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.0.1) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

The Samsung avd I created showed up but it's just blank screen

What am I doing wrong? The project that I used is https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu

Any ideas?

Comment: Update guys! I changed the emulator from android to ios. In no time at all, it worked!!!

Answer (score 8):

**Just restart the virtual device solved my problem!** I use Android Studio.

I had the same problem when I run following command:

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

It prints a lot of dots like this:

[image]

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: We have the same issue. It does not happen consistent, sometimes it shows the dots. A colleage encounters this problem more then me. We're still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Those infinite dots happen when your virtual device doesn't load correctly.

Just restart it and the problem is solved.